# How Get ALL photos with out filepicker

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I m  make a simple window phone 8.1 app i want to get aLl photos to display in  app and then user select  PickMultipleFilesAndContinue  ..... but im dont know how to do it . i made this code openfiler picker taking me to phone library ..... Is there any other way to get photos in windows phone 8.1  ?

```
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();
        view.Activated += view_Activated;
    }
        private async void view_Activated(CoreApplicationView sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.IActivatedEventArgs args1)
    {


            FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args = args1 as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;

            bitmapImages = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = args.Files;
            if (files.Count > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Picked files:\n");
                // Application now has read/write access to the picked file(s)
                foreach (StorageFile file in files)
                {
                    output.Append(file.Name + "\n");

                    using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                            bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 200;
                            bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
                            bitmapImages.Add(bitmapImage);

                        }
                        catch (ArgumentException Ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Exception ", Ex.Message);
                        }

                    }
                }
                ImageCollection.ItemsSource = bitmapImages;
                OutputTextBlock.Text = output.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                OutputTextBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
            }

    }
```

by this im geting only selected photos . i want all to display and then user select from them .....

Answer (score 1):

You can access the photos programmatically and then add them to your ImageCollection. I've resized the photos, because otherwise the App crashes on my phone.

```
StorageFolder pictureFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary; //or another folder
IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> nameList = await pictureFolder.GetItemsAsync();
var bitmapImages = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

foreach (var item in nameList)
{
    if (item is StorageFile)
    {
        if (item.Name.Substring(item.Name.Length - 4, 3).ToLower() == "jpeg" || item.Name.Substring(item.Name.Length - 3, 3).ToLower() == "jpg" || item.Name.Substring(item.Name.Length - 3, 3).ToLower() == "png")
        {
            Image image = new Image();
            StorageFile file = await pictureFolder.GetFileAsync(item.Name);
            IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);
            if (bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight >= bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth)
            {
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight / 100;
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 100;
            }
            else
            {
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth / 100;
                bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
            }
            bitmapImages.Add(bitmapImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dnt want to add them separately  .. the code i post here is working fine and adding the picture in ImageCollection but show all camra rolling picture in imageCollectoin THen User select form it .. i dont want user to get in camra rolling

Comment: @AS Khan Maybe I wrote it unfavorably. You doesn't have to add the photos separately, the code does it automatically. And instead of using `listView.Items.Add(image);` you can use `bitmapImages.Add(bitmapImage);`. Take a look at my edited answer.